# How to get access to `BsModalRef` in opened modal component?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng2-bootstrap, modalpopup, ngx-bootstrap

I'm quite new to Angular 4.I have been working on Angular 1.5.x and now converting same application in Angular 4 with `ngUpgrade` hybrid approach.
I'm using `ngx-bootstrap` modal component in my hybrid application in order to replace existing modal service.

I found some problem in following guide [ngx-bootstrap-modal with service](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-examples).

Having problem with this statement `If you passed a component to .show() you can get access to opened modal by injecting BsModalRef`

I'm copying same example here,

```
export class ModalContentComponent {
  public title: string;
  public list: any[] = [];
  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}  // How do you get bsModalRef here
}
```

I try running this example, but I never get `bsModalRef` in opened modal.

I also try passing `bsModalRef` through `content`, but it work with one modal and failed to work with nested modal.

Is there any other way to pass `bsModalRef` in  `ModalContentComponent` ?

Find complete example here,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';

@Component({
 selector: 'demo-modal-service-component',
 templateUrl: './service-component.html'
})
export class DemoModalServiceFromComponent {
 bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

public openModalWithComponent() {
let list = ['Open a modal with component', 'Pass your data', 'Do something else', '...'];
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent);
this.bsModalRef.content.title = 'Modal with component';
this.bsModalRef.content.list = list;
setTimeout(() => {
  list.push('PROFIT!!!');
}, 2000);
}
}

/* This is a component which we pass in modal*/

@Component({
 selector: 'modal-content',
 template: `
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <ul *ngIf="list.length">
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">Close</button>
</div>
 `
})
 export class ModalContentComponent {
  public title: string;
  public list: any[] = [];
  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {} // How do you get bsModalRef here

 }
```

Comment: show your full code, where you call `modalService.show()` or better yet create a plunker

Comment: @Maximus added full code

Comment: Okay, what component do you expect `BsModalRef` should refer to? Can you setup a simple plunker?

Comment: `ModalContentComponent `  expect `BsModalRef`

Comment: okay, need a plunker

Comment: @Maximus not sure about plunker. I following same guide from http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-examples

Comment: can't help without the reproducible plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using

> import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Thanks to `ngx-bootstap` community on GitHub - [Problem solution](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2348)

Answer (score 3):

This issue is because of multiple references or circular references.

You should import all the ngx-bootstrap components, services directly from the `ngx-bootstrap` instead of going to the specific file.

```
import { BsModalRef,ModalModule ,BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/lO2NBD9hHNXbNtiruqyT)**

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by Import

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
```